# Who would doubt it?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

How does one render in French expressions such as "Who would doubt it?", "Who would think so?" More specifically, is it more appropriate to use the conditional tense (*Qui douterait ça ?"*), or the imperfect (*Qui doutait ça ?*), or perhaps there is an equivalent French expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conditional is what I would use:

> *Qui douterait **de** ça ?*
>
> *Qui en douterait ?*
>
> *Qui pourrait en douter ?*
>
> *Qui penserait ça ?*
>
> *Qui le penserait ?*
>
> *Qui pourrait penser ça ?*

Comment: I'm glad to see that "Qui en douterait?" is idiomatic and on your list because I really like to use "en" and that's what first came to my non-native mind to use with "douterait."  I was even tempted to think that "en" might work with "penserait," but your bolding of "**de**" at the top of the list reminded me that "penser" takes a direct object.  To satisfy my desire to use/overuse "en" whenever I can get away with it, could "en" be used with "croirait" or even "**se** douterait" to approximate the notion of "Who would think so/that"?:ie, "Qui en croirait?/Qui s'en douterait?"?

Comment: @PapaPoule *Qui en penserait ?* doesn't work indeed but *qui en penserait autrement ?* while rare is possible. *Qui penserait à ça ?* is possible, but the meaning is slightly different ("think about it" vs "think so"). *Qui en croirait ?*  doesn't work alone, but is possible in, for example, *qui en croirait un seul mot ?*, otherwise that's *qui y croirait ?*. *Qui s'en douterait ?* is possible but the meaning is the opposite: *Qui en douterait ?* means everyone is expected to believe it while *Qui s'en douterait ?* means everyone is expected not to guess it.

Comment: Thank you! The point about the preposition is also a revealing one. Although now I am confused about *penser à qqch/qqn*: could it also be: *Qui y penserait?*

Comment: Yes, *qui y penserait ?* is fine for *penser à qqch/qqn*. TLFi: *Je pensai à Anne. J'y pensai d'une telle manière que je m'assis sur mon lit, le cœur battant (Sagan, Bonjour tristesse, 1954, p. 76).*

Answer (score 1):

Qui aurait des doutes là-dessus ?

Qui mettrait ça en doute ?

Chez qui ça éveillerait des doutes ?

Comment: I like your answer too. However it has less of the idiomatic sense that I was looking for. Thanks!